# Issue with launch image in iPhone 6S plus and iPhone 7 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, launchimage

I am quite new to Xcode. I have certain images for launch screen of my app. I have added them using drag and drop to the icons (Images.xassets -> LaunchImage).

All of them works properly in all devices except iPhone 6s plus and iPhone 7 plus.

My contents.json file looks like this

```
{

 "images" : [
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_640x1136.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_640x1136-1.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "subtype" : "retina4",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_750x1334.png",
  "extent" : "to-status-bar",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_750x1334-1.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "landscape",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_landscape_1136x640.png",
  "extent" : "to-status-bar",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "landscape",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_landscape_1136x640-1.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_1536x2048.png",
  "extent" : "to-status-bar",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_1536x2048-1.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "landscape",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_landscape_2048x1536-2.png",
  "extent" : "to-status-bar",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "landscape",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_landscape_2048x1536-3.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "736h",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_1080x1920.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "scale" : "3x"
},
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "736h",
  "filename" : "iOS_landscape_2048x1536-1.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
  "orientation" : "landscape",
  "scale" : "3x"
},
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "667h",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_750x1334-2.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "retina4",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_640x1136-2.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_750x1334-3.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "landscape",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_landscape_1334x750.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_1536x2048-2.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "landscape",
  "idiom" : "ipad",
  "filename" : "iOS_landscape_2048x1536.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
  "scale" : "2x"
}
],
"info" : {
  "version" : 1,
  "author" : "xcode"
}
}
```

I am using Xcode 8 and deployment target is iOS 10.0

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would suggest using a launch storyboard. Add a UIImage view, constrain it to the screen edges and let iOS scale the image for you

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "736h",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_1080x1920.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "scale" : "3x"
},
```

to

```
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "736h",
  "filename" : "iOS_portrait_1242x2208.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "scale" : "3x"
},
```

and make sure your image iOS_portrait_1242x2208.png resolution is really **1242x2208**.